# can't send any ETH from mist wallet

Tags: mist, bug

can't apply any contract, cant send any ETH. Mist is on the actual block, time is updated - nothing works. what to do? on etherscan it still shows my balance. always stuck on 0 out of 12 confirmations

Comment: can you provide the transaction link on etherscan?

Comment: And provide screenshots when you are trying to make a transaction please.

Comment: it doesn't show any pending tx... and no tx with internal errors. it seems like it doenst even start any contract, since it doesn't substract any ETH when i try to start a contract. here is a screenshot from the transaction:

https://ibb.co/cqsnv6

Comment: still not working...

Comment: i am thinking about deleting my chain and resyncing.
But how can i save my wallets, so i don't lose my ETH stuck in it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it myself by deleting the chaindata and resyncing... nothing else worked.

thx m8s

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to myetherwallet (or any other wallet that lets you adjust gas price)
2) Using the same account for which you are having troubles deploying, send 0 ether from that account to any account of your choosing
3) Set the gas price significantly higher than the previous transactions (for good measure I just go for 2x higher gas price)
4) Increase gas limit (not clear whether or not this has any impact)
5) Send transaction

This one should show up in the blockchain explorers, and once it's marked as successful you should be able to start sending transactions again. Not sure exactly why but I think it has to do with the nonce.